# Error when submitting jQuery/Ajax form second time in FF

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML outputted code:

```
<tr class="uedit103" style="display: none;"><form  id="editform103" name="editform103">
    <td class="base" id="uedit103"><input type="text" class="editua" name="lname" id="lname" value="inte"></td>
    <td class="base" id="uedit103"><input type="text" value="info" class="editua" name="fname" id="fname" ></td>
    <td class="base" id="uedit103"><input type="text" value="email@email.com" class="edituaxl" name="emailadres" id="emailadres" ></td>
    <td class="yellow       
    "><select name="ma_accesslevel"><option value="0" >Basic</option><option value="1"  SELECTED >Intermediate</option><option value="2" >Superuser</option></select></td>
    <td class="yellow

    "><select name="m_accesslevel"><option value="0" >Basic</option><option value="1"  SELECTED >Intermediate</option><option value="2" >Superuser</option></select></td>
    <td class="yellow
    "><select name="hcc_accesslevel"><option value="0" >Basic</option><option value="1"  SELECTED >Intermediate</option><option value="2" >Superuser</option></select></td>
    <td class="base" id="uedit103"><input type="hidden" class="editua" name="uid" id="uid" value="103"></td>
    <td class="base" id="uedit103"><input type="button" id="editsubmit103" class="editbutton" Value="Save"><input type="button" id="editcancel103" class="editbutton" Value="Cancel"></td>
    </form></tr>
```

The jQuery part is this (alert added for debugging):

```
$('#editsubmit$ses->user_id').click(function(){
    $.post('ajax/aj_edituser.php', $("form#editform$ses->user_id").serialize(), function(result) {
        alert($("form#editform$ses->user_id").serialize());
        $('#success$ses->user_id').delay(200).fadeToggle('slow').delay(2000).fadeToggle('slow');    
        $('div.mainadmin').html(result);            
    });
});
```

Works in all browsers, except FF, which fails the second time the form is submitted (the form is reloaded in the open page). When validating the HTML, or looking into the source code in FF, the form tag

```
<form  id="editform103" name="editform103">
```

is put in red and gets the message "Start tag form seen in table". The closing form tag is also put in red and gets the message "Stray end tag form".
Validating the code via http://validator.w3.org/ also gives me these errors + "Element form not allowed as child of element tr in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)" on the editform. So I've tried putting the form around the  tags too, but didn't help.

I don't see this anymore, anyone who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It invalid HTML to put form tag inside TR tag or TABLE tag, you need to put it eather inside TD or around the whole TABLE

Comment: ok, so I should create a new TABLE inside my TR and FORM tags to capture all the fields in the different TD's in the form?

Comment: Do you want to have a single form on page or several , one per tr row ?

Comment: I need one form per TR row. It's an overview of users, and they need to be editable per row.

Comment: In this case you will need to create a table for each row and so-round them with form tags like, <TABLE><TR><TD><FORM><TABLE><TR><TD></TD></TR></TABLE></FORM></TD></TR></TABLE>, bur it not a nice way of doing things , it better in this case to construct your post request in Jquery and not using forms on page

Comment: You mean instead of using the form in HTML and serialize() in jQuery, not using a form at all, and use inputname.value() in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$('#editsubmit$ses->user_id').on('click', function(){ ... }
```

If you're going to create HTML elements with Javascript you should use `.on()` to bind events.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Hope it help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Indeed, this is more correct I suppose, but too bad, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, you should use `.on()` if you're going to be creating dynamic elements, but *not like that*. You need to set up event delegation, which uses a slightly different syntax.

Comment: you can use or not the delegation.